# get the context from an non-activity class into a non-activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-context

I'd like to get access from my database which is the **DBAdapter.class** *(not an activity)* into another non-activity class that randoms data **RandomData.class**

my sample code was like:

```
DBAdapter getAvailRandom=new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
 getAvailRandom.open();
 ...
 ....
 ...

 getAvailRandom.close();
```

`getApplicationContext()` is always undefined

I tried `getActivity.getApplicationContext()` and `Activity.this` , but still not working

Answer (score 4):

You need to create One Argument `Constructor` and pass `Context` like

```
private Context mContext;

public DBAdapter(Context con){
        mContext = con;
}
```

in your `DBAdapter` class

```
DBAdapter getAvailRandom=new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: OP is using `getApplicationContext()` in `RandomData` instead of in `DBAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Pass Context to non-Activity class in there constructor and use that reference where you want. eg

```
public     DBAdapter(Context mCtx){

this.mCtx = mCtx;

}
```

And for RandomData

```
public RandomData(Context mCtx){

this.mCtx = mCtx;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the context to the constructor or method you are calling.

```
private Context mContext;

public RandomData(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

Edit:

Just for fun, you can actually get the application context in a static way. This is **not** recommended:

```
public static Context getContext() {
        Context context = null;
        try {
            Class<?> activityThreadClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");
            Method method = activityThreadClass.getMethod("currentApplication");
            context = (Application) method.invoke(null, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        return context;
}
```

Comment: OP is using `getApplicationContext()` in `RandomData` instead of in `DBAdapter`

Comment: It sounds like he/she might be having issues in both classes. Either way the same concept applies.

Comment: if OP is getting `The DBAdapter constructor is undefined` then `DBAdapter(Context context)..`  answer apply

Answer (score 0):

You can not access `getApplicationContext()` in normal java class so you will need to use `RandomData` class constructor to get Context from Activity as:

```
Context context;
RandomData(Context context){
  this.context=context;
}
```

Now pass context in `DBAdapter` constructor :

```
DBAdapter getAvailRandom=new DBAdapter(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to avoid storing a reference to the whole context of your application and rendering the non-activity class dependent on the lifespan of your context is to provide (static-)methods which take a context as an parameter.

In this manner:

```
public static void doDbStuff(Context context, ...) { .. }
```